# Failure to change the volume on Samsung Smart TV using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

We have created basic JavaScript app for Samsung Smart TV. When we are changing volume nothing is happened.  We do it in this way:

```
deviceapis.audiocontrol.setVolumeUp()
```

and

```
deviceapis.audiocontrol.setVolumeDown()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you tell us what interface you're using ? Maybe some more information would be extremely helpful.

Comment: We are using Smartbox and Samsung Smart TV SDK for windows

Answer (score 0):

If you want change volume on TV, first way - use native buttons VolUp and VolDown:

```
//add plugin object in your html file
<object id="pluginObjectNNavi" border=0 classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NNAVI"></object>
```

then, when document loaded, run script:

```
var nnaviPlugin = document.getElementById('pluginObjectNNavi');
if (nnaviPlugin) {
    nnaviPlugin.SetBannerState(1);
}
var pluginAPI = new Common.API.Plugin();
pluginAPI.unregistKey(tvKey.KEY_VOL_UP);
pluginAPI.unregistKey(tvKey.KEY_VOL_DOWN);
pluginAPI.unregistKey(tvKey.KEY_MUTE);
```

Second way - add Audio plugin and use api (setVolume, setVolumeUp, setVolumeDown):

```
//add plugin object in your html file
<OBJECT id='pluginObjectAudio' border=0 classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-AUDIO' style='opacity:0.0;background-color:#000000;width:0px;height:0px;'></OBJECT>
```